# Getting a user's Facebook friends with graph api

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get Facebook friends list of a specific user using a access token.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/

But how to get the `friend-list-id`?

So far this is an example of all I am able to get.

https://graph.facebook.com/fbID/friends?access_token=appid|appsecret

Comment: Friend lists are only the lists users can create on Facebook, to “sort” their friends into different categories. From this endpoint, you will get the list id and name only – you will _not_ get which users are on those lists. `/me/friends` is what you need to get the friends of the user that are users of your app as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `me/friends` after they've logged in. The response will be an Array you can loop over, so you can get each User `id` property and make more calls to `FB.api()` using the id, if desired.

This is probably what you want to do:

```
fbAsyncInit = function(){
  FB.init({
    appId: 'yourAppIdHere',
    version: 'v2.5'
  });
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(response.status === 'connected'){
      FB.api('me/friends', function(a){
        for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
          /* make a call for each friend with more .api calls - a is array of User objects - props seen here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ */
          FB.api(a[i].id, function(r){
          });
        }
      });
    }
    else{
      location = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=replaceThisWithAppId&redirect_uri='+location;
      // change out replaceThisWithAppId above
    }
  });
}
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
})(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
```